# Postgres - SQL query count by 2 columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in Postgres:

```
zone_name | trade_name   | client_name
G - WLA   | Garage Doors | King Garage Doors
J - SOC   | Attic        | Attic Jimmy
E - SGV2  | Attic        | Attic Jimmy
J - SOC   | Closets      | Brad Factory
E - SGV2  | Closets      | Brad Factory
AE - SFE  | Paint        | Chris Painting
E - SGV2  | Kitchen      | Joe Remodeling
```

I trying to create a table that shows how many clients (`client_name`) are in the same `trade_name` within the same `zone_name`.

I've been trying to use `GROUP BY` but couldn't figure it out.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: `select count(client_name), trade_name, zone_name
    from table
    group by  trade_name, zone_name` ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze I think that works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` on two columns. In the following query, I use `group by 1, 2` -- this is a convenient way to group by on the first two columns from `SELECT` clause.

Also, I put two different `count()` to the query – probably, you will find that in your case it's more semantically correct to use `count(distinct ..)`.

```
select 
  zone_name,
  trade_name,
  count(client_name) as count_clients,
  count(distinct client_name) as count_distinct_clients
from table
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2
;
```

BTW, `count(client_name)` will not count rows, where `client_name` is NULL.

You can probably also find useful a new (9.5+) fancy feature, `GROUPING SETS` (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html), which will give you counts not only for groups of `(zone_name, trade_name)` pairs, but for also for "single column" groups for `zone_name` and `trade_name`, in a single query (here I also use numerical order aliasing):

```
select 
  zone_name,
  trade_name,
  count(client_name) as count_clients,
  count(distinct client_name) as count_distinct_clients
from table
group by grouping sets ((1, 2), 1, 2)
order by 1, 2
;
```